# How to get groups of numbers separated by commas in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
Cluster 7: {4, 15, 21, 28, 33, 35, 43, 47, 53, 57, 59, 66,
       69, 70, 74, 86, 87, 88, 90, 114, 136, 148, 201,
       202, 212, 220, 227, 250, 252, 253, 259, 262, 267,
       270, 282, 296, 318, 319, 323, 326, 341}
Cluster 8: {9, 10, 11, 20, 39, 55, 79, 101, 108, 143, 149,
       221, 279, 284, 285, 286, 287, 327, 333, 334, 335,
       336}
Cluster 9: {3, 64, 83, 93, 150, 153, 264, 269, 320, 321, 322}
Cluster 10: {94, 123, 147}
```

And i want to extract by cluster the number in each set.

I have tryed using regex without much luck

I have tried:

```
regex="(Cluster \d+): \{((\d+)[,\}][\n ]+)+|(?:(\d+),[\n ])"
```

But the groups dont match.

I would like an output as:

```
["Cluster 7", '4', '15', '21', '28', '33', '35', '43', '47', '53', '57', '59', '66', '69', '70', '74', '86', '87', '88', '90', '114', '136', '148', '201', '202', '212', '220', '227', '250', '252', '253', '259', '262', '267', '270', '282', '296', '318', '319', '323', '326', '341', "Cluster 8", '9', '10', '11', '20', '39', '55', '79', '101', '108', '143', '149', '221', '279', '284', '285', '286', '287', '327', '333', '334', '335', '336', "Cluster 9", '3', '64', '83', '93', '150', '153', '264', '269', '320', '321', '322', "Cluster 10", "94", "123", "147"]
```

Or maybe this is not the best approach to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a more generic regex:

```
import re
s = '\nCluster 7: {4, 15, 21, 28, 33, 35, 43, 47, 53, 57, 59, 66,\n       69, 70, 74, 86, 87, 88, 90, 114, 136, 148, 201,\n       202, 212, 220, 227, 250, 252, 253, 259, 262, 267,\n       270, 282, 296, 318, 319, 323, 326, 341}\nCluster 8: {9, 10, 11, 20, 39, 55, 79, 101, 108, 143, 149,\n       221, 279, 284, 285, 286, 287, 327, 333, 334, 335,\n       336}\nCluster 9: {3, 64, 83, 93, 150, 153, 264, 269, 320, 321, 322}\nCluster 10: {94, 123, 147}\n'
data = re.findall('Cluster \d+|\d+', s)
```

Output:

```
['Cluster 7', '4', '15', '21', '28', '33', '35', '43', '47', '53', '57', '59', '66', '69', '70', '74', '86', '87', '88', '90', '114', '136', '148', '201', '202', '212', '220', '227', '250', '252', '253', '259', '262', '267', '270', '282', '296', '318', '319', '323', '326', '341', 'Cluster 8', '9', '10', '11', '20', '39', '55', '79', '101', '108', '143', '149', '221', '279', '284', '285', '286', '287', '327', '333', '334', '335', '336', 'Cluster 9', '3', '64', '83', '93', '150', '153', '264', '269', '320', '321', '322', 'Cluster 10', '94', '123', '147']
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not use regex for this.  Your text is within [`yaml`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) spec and can be loaded directly with [an order-preserving yaml loader such as oyaml](https://github.com/wimglenn/oyaml).

```
import oyaml as yaml   # pip install oyaml
data = yaml.load(text)
```

To unpack that dict to the desired "flat" structure, it's just a list comprehension:

```
[x for (k, v) in data.items() for x in (k, *v)]
```

<sub>*Note:* I'm the author of oyaml.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/nANdbG/1)

```
\w+(?: +\w+)?
```

- `\w+` Match one or more word characters
- `(?: +\w+)?` Optionally match the following

  - `+` Match one or more spaces
  - `\w+` Match one or more word characters

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TVDRasMwDHzvV5g8tdSUSLIdpzD6sN/Iy2AZC3RpSTPGGP327M5jNAFJ1kVn3fn6Pb9fRluW4eN6mWY39ZvNzT256vn8eZv7yTVH9xO8k@idCiJ7Z4ZAH1BD411Ejaytdyn5bnR/X0Lf1Ajwc0JgJoPfAhPhpQZUAiCt5cHTWrmMSWsm8DTyFIlxnXKXJrapWTG5TjPhFlebUK1g1JSalViQezf@u8twh99SFFEGBtBHuGsKLkyZKo2pXe0qz8EpzYGJL0SbSp9G0VZeygJTfDDN0kpCCwkYS5jqRhxaLqJbKUaJayoWKI5LTXXFl5oe@JpaJDb3anOdhnHeTv3hbRhfX87n7VR1X/vt6ej2qLtT5d1tt1uWXw)

```
import re

s = "Cluster 7: {4, 15, 21, 28, 33, 35, 43, 47, 53, 57, 59, 66,\n       69, 70, 74, 86, 87, 88, 90, 114, 136, 148, 201,\n       202, 212, 220, 227, 250, 252, 253, 259, 262, 267,\n       270, 282, 296, 318, 319, 323, 326, 341}\nCluster 8: {9, 10, 11, 20, 39, 55, 79, 101, 108, 143, 149,\n       221, 279, 284, 285, 286, 287, 327, 333, 334, 335,\n       336}\nCluster 9: {3, 64, \n3, 93, 150, 153, 264, 269, 320, 321, 322}\nCluster 10: {94, 123, 147}"
print(re.findall(r"\w+(?: +\w+)?", s))
```

Result:

```
['Cluster 7', '4', '15', '21', '28', '33', '35', '43', '47', '53', '57', '59', '66', '69', '70', '74', '86', '87', '88', '90', '114', '136', '148', '201', '202', '212', '220', '227', '250', '252', '253', '259', '262', '267', '270', '282', '296', '318', '319', '323', '326', '341', 'Cluster 8', '9', '10', '11', '20', '39', '55', '79', '101', '108', '143', '149', '221', '279', '284', '285', '286', '287', '327', '333', '334', '335', '336', 'Cluster 9', '3', '64', '83', '93', '150', '153', '264', '269', '320', '321', '322', 'Cluster 10', '94', '123', '147']
```